# Adaptive constraints for same size classes

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm making an iOS app and at the moment I'm trying to achieve a nice look on all the iPhones. I hoped I could use autolayout features to make it work, but all the iPhones in portrait mode have the same size classes. That's why I decided to change constraint constants depending on a screen size. But somehow it's not working. Basically, I have a numpad as a stack view, which has a height constraint. But when I change its constant programmatically, it does not change anything in the simulator.

```
@IBOutlet weak var keyboard: UIStackView!

//instantiating constraints

@IBOutlet weak var numpadHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchSettings()

    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

    if screenHeight == 568 {
        print("SE")
        print(numpadHeight.constant)
        numpadHeight.constant = 100
    } else if screenHeight == 667 {
        print("7")
        numpadHeight.constant = 256
    } else if screenHeight == 736 {
        print("7+")
    }

    print(numpadHeight.constant)

...}
```

I also tried setLayoutIfNeeded(), does not help

Comment: If you are doing this, then you may as well not use autolayout. You should set your constraints so that the height of your views adjust automatically; use an aspect ratio constraint, for example.

Comment: Have you tried anything in *viewWillLaoutSubviews()* or *viewDidLayoutSubviews()*? While I've never checked *screen* bounds in viewDidLoad(), it's usually the case the view bounds/frames aren't yet set.

Comment: I use bounds in viewDidLoad and they work just fine. Can I set a constraint so my numpad takes 30% of superview space?

Comment: print(keyboard.frame.height) returns 100, how is this possible?